# Get direct Java Method by Class Accessor

Tags: java, methods, reflection

Is there some way to get a `java.lang.reflect.Method` object by direct access? Like `MyUtils::sum` in my example below:

```java
class MyUtils {
    static int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

java.lang.reflect.Method myUtilsSumMethod = MyUtils::sum;
int sum = myUtilsSumMethod.invoke(null, 2, 3); // should be 5
```

Or do I always have to use the string name using reflection API?

```java
MyUtils.class.getDeclaredMethod("sum", Integer.class, Integer.class)
```

Because as soon as I refactor the name of the method, I will get an exception at Runtime and I would like to have the error already during compile time.

Comment: `Method` is a reflection artifact, so it can only be gotten via reflection. Depending on what you want to do with it `MuyUtils::sum` can be useful, but it can't do everything that `Method` does. Can you tell us what the underlying goal is with the `Method` object? It's possible that getting rid of reflection/`Method` entirely is the best solution for your problem, but it's hard to tell with the details you gave here. `IntBinaryOperator op = MyUtils::sum` might be what you need.

Comment: If you can afford to reference the "Method" statically, then you don't need reflection. Now is a good time to take another look at your design.

Comment: it is not about the architecture/design etc. I was just wondering if I can get a Method object somehow via language level and not via the reflection API. So e.g. I want to get the annotations of some Method, then I always have to use the way via `.class.getDeclaredMethods`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need reflection here - `MyUtils::sum` returns a method reference that you can store in an `IntBinaryOperator`:

```java
IntBinaryOperator myUtilsSumMethod = MyUtils::sum;
int sum = myUtilsSumMethod.applyAsInt(2, 3); // should be 5
```